# TensorFlow Cannot feed value of shape (100, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am learning TensorFLow. So to understand how to make something, I tried to copy some code from a source and execute it. But I'm hitting an error message. So I tried some solution from this website but it does not work (I kept my test in comments).

```
    """programme 1 """
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)





X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 28, 28, 1]) #28 * 28 taille image 1 = 1pixel car noir et blanc "X" valeur
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10])) # 28*28 = 784 , 10 -> 0 à 9  "W" = weight = poid
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10])) #chiffre de 0 à 9 a reconnaitre "b" = constante 
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

#model
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X,[-1, 784]), W) + b) #fonction "matmul": produit matriciel "-1": reussite obligatoire

#Place holder
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

#loss function
cross_entropy = -1 * tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y)) #formule

# % of correct annwer found in batch
is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1),tf.argmax(Y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct,tf.float32))

#training step
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003) #petit pas
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) 

for i in range(10000):
    #load batch of image and ocrrects answer
    batch_X, batch_Y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    batch_X = np.reshape(batch_X, (-1, 784))
    #batch_Y = np.reshape(batch_Y, (-1, 784))

    train_data = {X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}

    #train
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)

    a,c = sess.run([accuracy,cross_entropy],feed = train_data)

    test_data = {X:mnist.test.images, Y_:mnist.test.labels}
    a,c = sess.run([accuracy,cross_entropy],feed = test_data)
```

the log :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\tensorflow\test1.py", line 46, in <module>
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)
  File "C:\Users\Proprietaire\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Proprietaire\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1100, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28, 1)'
2017-08-30 19:07:37.406994: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

line 46 is

```
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because there is a mismatch between the shape of what you are feeding in and what the TensorFlow is expecting. To fix the issue, you might want to reshape your data at `placeholder:0` which is `batch_X` to 
`(?, 28, 28, 1)`. For example, you would do the following:

```
batch_X = np.reshape(batch_X, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape X.

```
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [None ,28 , 28 , 1])
    X = tf.reshape(X , [-1 , 784])
```

Answer (score -1):

When you define a placeholder in TensorFlow, the shape of the input during the session should be the same as the shape of the placeholder.

In `batch_X, batch_Y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)`, the `batch_x` is a **2D** array of pixel values, which will have a shape of `[batch_size, 28*28]`.

In `X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 28, 28, 1])`, the input placeholder is defined to have a **4D** shape of `[batch_size, 28, 28, 1]`

You can either 1) reshape `batch_x` before the feeding to TensorFlow. e.g.`batch_x = np.reshape(batch_x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])` or 2) Change the shape of the placeholder. e.g. `X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 784])`

I would recommend 2), since this saves you from doing any reshaping operations both in and outside of the TensorFlow graph.