# run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'feed'

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, mnist

I'm started on tensorflow and I'm trying to read handwritten letters from a MNIST. I've got an error in my code but I don't understand why. I've found a post which is similar to this one but i've got the same error with this code. (link of this topic [TensorFlow Cannot feed value of shape (100, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966301/tensorflow-cannot-feed-value-of-shape-100-784-for-tensor-placeholder0/46876972#46876972))

```
enter code here import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,28,28,1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
B = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
#Model
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X,[-1,784]),W)+B)
#Placeholder for correct answer
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
#Calcul de l'erreur
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y))  
# pourcentage de bonne réponse
is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1),tf.argmax(Y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct,tf.float32))

#Regression linéaire

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003)
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)
#Training process


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)  


for i in range(1000):
    #On charge les images
    batch_X,batch_Y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    batch_X = np.reshape(batch_X, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
    train_data = {X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}
#train
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = train_data)
#success ? 
a,c = sess.run([accuracy,cross_entropy],feed_dict = train_data) 

#success on train data ? 
test_data = {X:mnist.test.images, Y_:mnist.test.labels}
a,c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy],feed=test_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change last lines to:

```
test_images = np.reshape(mnist.test.images, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
test_data = {X:mnist.test.images, Y_:test_images}
a,c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy],feed_dict=test_data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've got a new error : 
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10000, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder_9:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28, 1)'